# How does Python represent the LinkedList in terms of memory reference?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Note: I prefer to not use any external module since it is for interview prep purpose.

I know that there is no a built-in linked-list DS in python. However, we can implement the linked-list through a class Node. In the following code, I did a method (intersect_ll) to find an intersection between two linkedlists where the definition of intersections: node(s) are in the same order and value in the both linkedlists:

```
class Node: 
  def __init__(self, data=None, next=None): 
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

class SingleLinkedList: 
  def __init__(self): 
    self.head = None

  def add_node(self, data):
    newNode = Node(data)
    
    if self.head:
        current = self.head
        while current.next: 
            current = current.next
        current.next = newNode

    else: 
        self.head = newNode
     
  def print_ll(self):
    current = self.head
    ll_data = []
    while current:
        ll_data +=  [current.data] 
        current = current.next
    return ll_data

  def intesect_ll (self, first_ll, second_ll):

    current_first = first_ll.head
    current_second = second_ll.head
     
    if current_first is None or current_second is None: 
        return False

    list_intersect = []

    while current_first and current_second:
        
        if current_first.data == current_second.data:
            list_intersect += [current_first.data] 
            
           
        current_first = current_first.next
        current_second = current_second.next
    
    for item in list_intersect:
        self.add_node(item)
    
    return self.print_ll()
```

**My Question is:** :

- I am pretty new to python so I am struggling to understand why comparing instead by memory reference is not working. In other word, why python did not give these two nodes with the same value and order in both linkedlists, the same memory location ?!. Is that because I am implementing my own data-structure and hence,I assume that python would take care of the rest which is not the reality?

  if current_first is current_second

*compiler result*:
it gives two different memory references for the both nodes of the same value and order in both linkedlists. Hence, this does not work and need to make it (.data) comparing by value then.

Comment: Implementing your own datastructure has a lot of bells and whistles attached to it. Instead of reinventing the wheel, maybe use one of the existing linked list libraries, like [`llist`](https://pypi.org/project/llist/)?

Comment: but I am afraid that It would not be acceptable in the interview (?) usually they do not like us to use libraries and modules.

Comment: You can compare objects by *identity* rather than *value* by using the `is` operator instead of `==`. How identity relates to memory location is an implementation detail of the Python interpreter you are using.

Comment: yeah, at the first place the memory identity is different according to my interpreter. I guess I will switch back to Java instead when having linkedlist problem. Like, what @GreenCloakGuy said, implementing my own DS would have a lot of bells and whistles.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that what I expect from python to do in terms of memory management is not that what really happens. I need to allocate the same object and then reference it in both linked lists in order to comparing by reference becomes a valid solution.

```
assign ObjectA : locationA in memory
linkedlist1: node.next --> LocationA ---> n nodes
linkedlist2:  node.next --> LocationA ----> k nodes
```

Otherwise, they are completely two different linkedlists and the interpreter would assign each one of the nodes into different memory location:

```
linkedlist1: node.next ---> locationX -- n nodes
linkedlist2: node.next ---> locationY --- k nodes
```

Hope that helps anyone would have the same concern